# Difference between Barberia and Barbiere

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between Barberia and Barbiere, and when it is appropriate to use them?

I am doing a sign for a Barber Shop who wants to use the Italian wording. The shop has a name of it's own, this word would be to let people know what kind of shop it is (example: A Cut Above - Barbershop).

From my understanding:

Barberia = Barber Shop

La Barberia = Barber Shop

Barbiere = Barber Shop OR Barber

Il Barbiere = The Barber

Which is the most commonly used in Italy?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6):

Il Barbiere = The Barber is correct;

The most common way in Italy to mean "Barber shop" is "Barbiere", too.

example:

> "Vado dal barbiere" (I am going to the barber shop)

or

> "Sei stato dal barbiere?" (Have you been at the barber shop?)

**Barberia** or **La Barberia**  ("La" is just the determiner, like "the") is in my experience quite uncommon; it seems also a bit "old-fashioned" word and I can't exclude that some barbers use it as a distinctive brand name for their shop.

p.s. *"vado dal barbiere"* is in fact a figure of speech (a metonymy if I am not wrong)

p.p.s. "Barberia" is also an old way to [denote a region in north Africa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/barberia/)

Comment: It shouldn't be ["barbieria"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/barbieria)? I mean, according to dictionaries "barberia" is an obsolete or regional form for "barbieria".

Comment: In fact the first meaning coming to my mind for *barberia* is the region of Africa, not the barber shop :).

Comment: `"Vado dal barbiere" (I am going to the barber shop)` or rather, I am going to the barber's.

Comment: Non giurerei che sia una metonimia: va effettivamente da un signore che di mestiere fa il barbiere, come quando vai dal medico o dal sarto.

Comment: @DaG pensavo alla metonimia in quando mi sembrava uno scambio della persona col luogo (vado dal barbiere /vado al negozio del barbiere)